# TestNG Assertion doesn't seem to be working with Cucumber / Gherkin Doc Strings?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, testng, cucumber-jvm

Iam currently attempt to use Cucumber Doc Strings, more information here: https://docs.cucumber.io/gherkin/reference/#gherkin-dialects however my code seems to be failing using a TestNG assertion to compare the feature file String against the String which is housed within my step file, any ideas?

My feature file:

```
  Scenario: Test
    Given then i should receive an email with the body off:
    """
    then i should receive an email with the body off
    then i should receive an email with the body off.
    """
```

My Step method:

```
@Given("^then i should receive an email with the body off:")
public void how_are_your(String arg1) {
    Assert.assertEquals(arg1, "then i should receive an email with the body off" + "\nthen i should receive an email with the body off.");
}
```

The assertion seems to fail, providing the following Exception:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected [then i should receive an email with the body off
then i should receive an email with the body off.] but found [then i should receive an email with the body off
then i should receive an email with the body off.]
```

Exception side by side:

```
expected [then i should receive an email with the body off
then i should receive an email with the body off.] 

found [then i should receive an email with the body off
then i should receive an email with the body off.]
```

Comment: This is a problem with the new line separator. Instead of using "/n" u could use System.lineSeparator(). Run the assertion code in debug mode and check the actual values being passed. What is the cucumber version u are using?